# Run django query outside of existing database transaction

Tags: django, postgresql, logging, transactions, soa

Project I'm involved relies on external services (SOA) and transaction management is turned on by default. However, in case of error, rolling back would cause some critical data loss like 'payment capture logging' (e.g. if code fails after capture has been made).

Is there a practical way to run a query outside current transaction? I always want external calls to be logged no matter what exceptions raise. I don't want to implement external logging service for convention. Savepoints won't take you there, maybe, another database connection needed for that moment?

Comment: A second database connection dedicated to your logging should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a practical way to run a query outside current transaction?

PostgreSQL doesn't natively support what you want, which is [autonomous (sub)transactions](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Autonomous_subtransactions).

You can simulate them with [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html), albeit clumsily. `dblink` does exactly what you suggested; it makes a connection from one PostgreSQL server to another. The connection may be the server connecting to its self.

If you can do this at the application level it's often better to do so, but dblink is certainly an option.